# Asp.net Session gets renewed between requests occasionally

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am building a website with asp.net and c# 3.5. 
The problem is User Session gets cleared between requests. Not all sessions, just that user session is renewed suddenly when a new request or postback occurs. 
I am using IIS7 and Win2008 R2. I Checked and found out that no recycling happens, WorkerProcess is set to 1, Website is not restarted. Just a user session is renewed and gets new sessionId. not all Sessions, just a user session is renewed.

It is A very strange problem, I searched the web and couldn't find the solution

If you have any clue?

Comment: What is the session time out set to in IIS?  In your web.config?

Comment: Are the users logged-in or anonymous on the site?

Comment: Some clues: 1)i have a log file in a folder calling App_Log, i created this folder myself and save my logs and exceptions in it. 2) i am using HttpContext.Current.Session to get and set my variables.

Comment: session timeout is not set, it is on its default 20minutes. It happens to the logged in users.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Forms Authentication? If so are you sure it's the Session timing out and not the Forms Auth cookie?

Comment: no, i'm not using ASP.NET Forms Authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found my problem, The problem name is "canonical domain". Users enter the site without www in start of its url, but between request ( especially in Respone.Redirect("~") or when i redirect user to payment gateway and when it returns back ), the url turns to a url with www. So the cookies renew and that user session lost in this point.

Canonical domain can be solved with IIS7 Url Rewrite module, in SEO -> Canonical domain name.